# How to tell the "recursive option" (-R) to skip a directory?

Tags: bash, terminal

I want to create a script that will periodically create a compressed backup file of an entire project folder, except for one directory.

My current command is this:

```
tar -czf backup.tar.gz /my/path/to/project -R
```

But I want it to ignore one specific directory in the project. In pseudo-ish code, something along the line of this:

```
tar -czf backup.tar.gz /my/path/to/project -R --skip-directory=subdir/skip_me
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `--exclude` option:

```
--exclude='/path/to/subdir/*'
```